# Esignature at web browser

Tags: java, browser, plugins, digital-signature, smartcard

Google Chrome and Opera will remove java plugin support. We are using applet to access Smart Card and sign a contract at client side. Do web browsers access a smart card natively or Is there any way to access a smart card without applet?

Thanks

Comment: Note that I've answered here, mainly because of the WebCrypto API. But generally you should ask this kind of question on our [security sister site](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this (in no particular order):

- implement a browser plugin (after that you can do anything)
- use the [WebCrypto API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/), if/when it is supported - note that this API is *under construction*
- use TLS for authentication to a secure web server, and sign something there

This is a hot topic, with many vendors having different solutions, none of which are perfect. You'll have to determine yourself which one fits your situation best.

Comment: Option 1 is not eligible due to managing and maintaining is very hard. You have to code for every browser.  Option 2 is not eligible due to under construction. And I don't understand option 3. Could you please give additional info or reference?

Comment: That's simply using a PKCS#11 library or CSP as a plugin to the security system of the browser / operating system (in case of Windows / IE and possibly Chrome). Then the browser is able to do TLS client authentication. Now authentication != non repudiation, so you need something more. There are certainly solutions out there that use Option 1 for sure. And there are non-browser solutions. As said, none of the options here is perfect. You could certainly say the same for the Java option by the way.

Comment: Is there a product off the shelf or any document/specs explained you mentioned as a plugin?